# How to correctly pin MSYS to task bar in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, mingw, msys

I use MSYS/MinGW a lot on Windows 8.1 and wanted to create a shortcut on the taskbar at the bottom. What I did is to lauch MSYS, and once it appears on the task bar, choose "pin this program to task bar".

This works for other things like Firefox, but not for MSYS. If I launch MSYS from the desktop, I get a shell prompt with username and hostname like this:
[image]

On the other hand, if I launch MSYS from the pinned icon on the task bar, I get a shell prompt with `sh.exe"-3.1$`

[image]

How do I create the shortcut correctly for MSYS?

Comment: My require a 3rd party app.  http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.140

Comment: Did you try dragging the executable for the program to the taskbar?

Comment: @Moab, I just tried to drag and drop it onto the taskbar, and the system does not allow me to do that. (8.1).